# Rails render partial via ajax with Shrine

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I am doing a file upload via Shrine and I am trying to refresh the div that lists links to the files via ajax once the files have been uploaded. I'm not sure how to set this up. Currently I am not getting any errors but it is also not refreshing on the update method.

Here is the section of the projects/show page I am looking to update:

```
      <div id="files" class="files">
            <% @project.uploads.each do |upload| %>
               <li><i class="fa fa-file"></i><%= link_to (upload.file.original_filename), upload.file.url %></li>
            <% end %>
      </div>
```

In my uploads_controller.rb

```
     def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @upload.update(upload_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @upload, notice: 'Upload was successfully updated.' }
            format.js
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: [@project, @upload] }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

uploads/update.js.erb

```
$('#files').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'uploads/upload') %>");
```

uploads/_upload.html.erb

```
<li><i class="fa fa-file"></i><%= link_to (upload.file.original_filename), upload.file.url %></li>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is the output from rails s when I upload a file. It is using shrine to upload the file to AWS.

```
   Started GET "/files/upload/cache/presign?extension=.png&_=1502552899536" for ::1 at 2017-08-12 11:48:19 -0400
    Started POST "/projects/1/uploads" for ::1 at 2017-08-12 11:48:19 -0400
    Processing by UploadsController#create as JSON
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dEfhUWvwOr10C8J+awEnSc+UO2J/wvG0wpbNm7WNM8TCzHXYNV+qjYHuKatiYvfwYRhc0Oj3yatjpjlVjeFFPQ==", "upload"=>{"file"=>"{\"id\":\"39ebdddc6ed2c5ac0d2951eac841b45b.png\",\"storage\":\"cache\",\"metadata\":{\"size\":11137,\"filename\":\"zen.png\",\"mime_type\":\"image/png\"}}"}, "project_id"=>"1"}
      User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      Project Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    The "mime_type" Shrine metadata field will be set from the "Content-Type" request header, which might not hold the actual MIME type of the file. It is recommended to load the determine_mime_type plugin which determines MIME type from file content.
       (0.0ms)  BEGIN
      SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "uploads" ("file_data", "created_at", "updated_at", "project_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["file_data", "{\"id\":\"39ebdddc6ed2c5ac0d2951eac841b45b.png\",\"storage\":\"cache\",\"metadata\":{\"size\":11137,\"filename\":\"zen.png\",\"mime_type\":\"image/png\"}}"], ["created_at", "2017-08-12 15:48:20.237871"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-12 15:48:20.237871"], ["project_id", 1]]
       (1.0ms)  COMMIT
       (0.0ms)  BEGIN
      SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "uploads" SET "file_data" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "uploads"."id" = $3  [["file_data", "{\"id\":\"a0451104edbd9b63238b0fddc766846d.png\",\"storage\":\"store\",\"metadata\":{\"size\":11137,\"filename\":\"zen.png\",\"mime_type\":\"image/png\"}}"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-12 15:48:20.464473"], ["id", 14]]
       (0.0ms)  COMMIT
      Rendering uploads/show.json.jbuilder
      Rendered uploads/_upload.json.jbuilder (1.0ms)
      Rendered uploads/show.json.jbuilder (4.0ms)
    Completed 201 Created in 533ms (Views: 92.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

Comment: Add some logs to try and understand what happens when you upload a file. But something I stumbled upon when I was doing this in my Rails app ( 5+ ) , if you move the format.js to be the first in execution, it works. It's because when there's a XHR request, Rails doesn't send the proper response to the controller, so by default, it will pick whatever's first in execution, in your case, HTML.

Comment: Thanks I moved the format.js to be first but it didn't make a difference. I'm new to rails so I'm not sure how to add logs?

Comment: If you just post whatever `rails s` outputs when you try and create a File it should be enough to start with.

Comment: Updated original post with the rails s output.

Comment: What's your JS code?

Comment: All I have is what I listed above in the update.js.erb file